# Почему не работает иконка font awesome?

Tags: fontawesome

Почему некоторые иконки не работают? (Это бесплатная иконка)

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fa-location-dot {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможно потому, что вы переопределяете класс fa-location-dot. Для изменения размера, цвета и т.д. используйте отдельный класс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А как Вы подключаете стили Font Awesome? При подключении css-файла с CDN всё работает.

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.fa-location-dot {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #222;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css">

<div>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Я тоже через CDN, но почему-то не работает

Comment: @Alexsander А если взять строку подключения, которую я использовал в ответе, и использовать в вашем проекте - сработает?

Comment: @Alexsander В самом вопросе отсутствует подключение css-файла, может добавите в вопрос вашу ссылку, которую вы подключаете?

Comment: да, ты прав css нужно было подключить, а не только js